# I'm not getting the APNs private key when converting to Certificates to PEM format

Tags: safari, push-notification, certificate, apple-push-notifications

I'm using this command to convert Certificates to PEM but I don't get the Private key :(

```
openssl x509 -in website_aps_production.cer -inform DER -out website_aps_production.pem -outform PEM
```

I only get the website_aps_production.pem

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved

```
openssl x509 -in website_aps_production.cer -inform DER -out website_aps_production.pem -outform PEM
```